# Check If Input String Is a Valid Math Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm going to check if input string is a valid mathematical expression. I have used `eval`, `Number` and `parseFloat`, but none of them worked correctly as shown bellow:

- I expect `eval('1//2')` to identify that the input is NOT valid, but it results in `1` which is not correct for me.
- I also expect `Number('2.5/6')` to be `0.4166666666666667`, but it results in `NaN` which is not correct for me.
- I also expect `parseFloat('1//2')` to identify that the input is NOT valid, but it results in `1` which is not correct for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am making the assumption that you only want +, -, /, and * operators. Here is a regex pattern that will match sequences of numbers separated by these operators:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?([+-/*]\d+(\.\d+)?)*$
```

Basically, it starts with a number, defined as at least 1 digit optionally followed by a mantissa:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

This is followed by 0 or more occurrences of an operator in conjunction with another number.

This will match simple numbers, as well as any series of operations, e.g. 1/2*3.2-5

Note: The reason eval() succeeded is because it executes the string as JavaScript, and // indicates what follows is a single-line comment. Also, ** is the exponentiation operator in JavaScript.